# Mocha test running twice - fails twice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, mocha.js

I have a mocha test that should fail, but in the terminal it runs it twice straight after one another.

```
describe('MySQL is functional', () => {
    //Check that the heathcheck is reporting
    it('indicates MySQL is running', done => {
        Request.get(healthcheckUrl, (err, res, body) => {
            //Decode the JSON
            let json = JSON.parse(body);

            assert.isOk(json.mysql === 'OK');
        }).then(err => done(err));
    });

});
```

Request.get returns a promise using the Request promise library.

Terminal output:

```
1) indicates MySQL is running
2) indicates MySQL is running
```

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Is that test within its own file that is referenced twice? Are there any other tests near this one that also run multiple times? Are there not? Your title says it fails the first time, but your output has the same for both test cases.

Comment: It seems that it only runs twice when it fails - if the test passes, then it will only run once. Title was misleading, there was a previous case where it would fail first, then fail. Now this one is just failing, but running twice.

Comment: do you have some where this set "this.retries(2);" Basically it says that re-run failed test cases for specified number of times.

Comment: No, I don't have that set anywhere in the code :)